# User Location (Latitude & Longitude) not updated quickly on Google Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-assistant

I'm using "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION" in Dialogflow to get the user's location (latitude and longitude). But the lat long I receive are the old ones. If a user moves, the latitude and longitude I receive from Google/Dialogflow take almost half an hour to get updated.

The location of Google maps shows the updated location, but I receive the old location from Dialogflow.

How can I get the latest latitude and longitude as soon as the user moves?

Answer (score 0):

The last time I tested this, it wasn't related to time of update - it was related to when the Assistant gets the precise location from a mobile device. It does not change the location while the Assistant is opened, but if you close the Assistant and re-open it, it will re-fetch the location.

In general - location services in the Assistant are poorly supported.

Comment: Tested the same. Closed the assistant, used fake gps to move the location (Google Map showed updated location), and then reopened the agent. Google Assistant showed the old location.